# R way to automatically assign numeric value to categorical column for modeling

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

This is a similar question to other posts, but I'm looking for a more automated solution than recode and solutions like that.

I have a column with many categories ie a city and would like to create a new column in R that assigns the city to a numeric value automatically like this:

```
City    CityCode
New York  0
New York  0
Boston    1
Boston    1
Chicago   2
New Haven 3
```

I have about 1,000 cities so it doesn't make sense to encode individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data$CityCode = as.integer(factor(data$City))` will work, ordering the Cities alphabetically by default. To put them in the order they occur in your data, `data$CityCode = as.integer(factor(data$City, levels = unique(data$City)))`.

There are very few modeling applications for which this is a good idea. (I'm having trouble thinking of any...) Make sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying out a k-means clustering algorithm, but also thought it was something good to know. I may code by state instead.

Comment: Yeah - for clustering I'd suggest getting actual data about the cities. There's no good reason that Chicago should be "1" away from Boston and New Haven, but "2" away from New York. But if you get population, some one-hot encoded regions, maybe some other data, you can get something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is with `match`

```
data$CityCode <- with(data, match(City, unique(City)))
```